# how to get the linear velocity in the robot heading direction with gazebo/link_states?

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic

my self-built URDF model of a differential drive robot. My purpose is to obtain the heading velocity of the robot. I am using the diff_drive_controller in ROS, which can publish the robot's velocity. The velocity is represented by **twist.linear.x**, indicating the linear velocity along the heading direction. However, I believe this velocity is not accurate. I am attempting to obtain the accurate velocity from the gazebo/link_states topic, which provides the output of the Gazebo simulation. Unfortunately, there is a problem. The twist message from Gazebo includes data in twist.linear.y, and I need to convert the velocity in the x and y directions from the world frame to the robot frame. There are two ways to achieve this. The first way is **sqrt(twist.linear.x  * twist.linear.x + twist.linear.y * twist.linear.y)**. However, this method might lose the information regarding forward or reverse motion. The second way is to use **twist.linear.x / cos(yaw)**, where yaw represents the robot's heading. What confuses me is that, in most cases, both methods calculate the velocity correctly. However, sometimes the velocities obtained through these formulas suddenly undergo mutation. For example, my robot's maximum speed is only 3 m/s, but occasionally, the calculated velocities become 9 or 10 m/s, which is clearly incorrect. I am unsure where the issue lies."
the code I use to get the yaw is as below

```
void localizationStateCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
    if (last_odom_time_ == NULL) {
        last_odom_time_ = new ros::Time();
    }
    cur_pose_.x = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
    cur_pose_.y = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
    cur_pose_.yaw = tf::getYaw(msg->pose.pose.orientation);
    cur_pose_.v =
        sqrt(msg->twist.twist.linear.x * msg->twist.twist.linear.x +
             msg->twist.twist.linear.y * msg->twist.twist.linear.y);
    cur_pose_.w = msg->twist.twist.angular.z;
    *last_odom_time_ = ros::Time::now();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the code I use to get the yaw is as below
nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg
cur_pose_.yaw = tf::getYaw(msg->pose.pose.orientation);
```

This is not the correct yaw value to use if you are working in the world frame. The odom msg reports the orientation of the robot in the odom frame.

I think that you should be using the orientation (yaw) from the same `gazebo_msgs/LinkStates` message where you got the world twist data.

Comment: I see what you mean,  actually  I wrote a python script to read the message in "gazebo_msgs/LinkStates" and convert it to "nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr" message type and publish to the message server.  After that, "localizationStateCallback" this callback function try to get the message.